# Extract text from html tags using reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, reduce

I'm trying to concatenate the inner HTML of each paragraph tag on my page in one single string using reduce. Here's my try:

```js
// JS
let par = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
document.write(par.reduce((a, b) => a + ", " + b.innerHTML));
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<p>Apple</p>
<p>Strawberry</p>
<p>Banana</p>
```

And here's the (wrong) output:

> [object HTMLParagraphElement], Strawberry, Banana

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce` function takes a 2nd argument which is the initial value for the `accumulator`.

By default, it's the first item in the array.

To have the desired result you should write your code like this:

```
let par = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
document.write(par.reduce((a,b)=>a+", "+b.innerHTML, ""));
```

Here is a document on `reduce` function from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a

Comment: Uuuh, I've tried this before posting, but put the initial value of the accumulator in the wrong place. I have to get used to that arrow notation! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should pass second parameter (initial value) for `reduce` method:

```
par.reduce((a,b)=>a+", "+b.innerHTML, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like:

```
let par = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
document.write(par.map(a=> a.innerHTML).join())
```

Comment: OP's asking about `reduce`, not about a general solution to the problem.

Comment: well maybe reduce is not the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As @hsz wrote you should use the empty string accumulator in order for your example to work:

```
let par = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p")); 
document.write(par.reduce(par.reduce((a,b) => a + ", " + b.innerHTML, '');
```

But you could also first map the array and get the innerHTML property and then reduce

```
let par = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p")); 
document.write(par.map(a => a.innerHTML).reduce((a, b) => a + ", " + b));
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to use `map` to create an array containing the actual content of your paragraphs.

Then by using `reduce`, passing the empty string as the accumulator *(2nd argument)*, you can get string combining the contents.

**Script:**

```js
/* Cache the p elements found. */
let pElems = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

/* Create an array containing the innerHTML of each 'p' element. */
let par = [].map.call(pElems, (a)=>a.innerHTML);

/* Use 'reduce' to combine them (passing the emoty string as the accumulator. */
document.write(par.reduce((a, b) => a + ", " + b), "");
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<p>Apple</p>
<p>Strawberry</p>
<p>Banana</p>
```

**One-liner:**

```js
document.write([].map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"), (a)=>a.innerHTML).reduce((a, b) => a + ", " + b), "");
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<p>Apple</p>
<p>Strawberry</p>
<p>Banana</p>
```